# nodelets in python

Tags: python, rospy, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all -- I don't know much about python threading nor how nodelets are actually implemented, so please pardon me if this is a stupid question, but is there any way to get nodelet functionality using rospy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46342/nodelets-in-python/) by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python being more dynamic doesn't need as much structure as C++ for loading plugins.  If you want to see an example of using plugins in python I suggest you take a look at [roswtf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roswtf).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2013-05-30**:
I haven't seen a explicit nodelet for python. It would be quite useful to mix, in the same nodelet manager, a python nodelet and a C++ nodelet